# How to parse with BeautifuSoup Python?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

For example I have code like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blablabla1">
        <div class="blablabla2">
            <div class="blablabla3">
                <span class="hello">Hello</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get `<span>` value or `<span>` class value?

Should I firstly find all containers?

Comment: Could you improve your question please - Provide some code, url of the website and also an expected result. That would make it more focused - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear but in generell you can access the `class` and `text` with css selector like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="container">
    <div class="blablabla1">
        <div class="blablabla2">
            <div class="blablabla3">
                <span class="hello">Hello</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

spanText = soup.select_one('div.container span').text
spanClass = soup.select_one('div.container span')['class']
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have obtain the soup, you can use the `find_all()` method to find all `<span>` with the hello `class`:

`all_hello_spans = soup.find_all({"span":{"class":"hello"}}})`